# How many calls?

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:

Let's say that we know that for each 100 random phone calls that you make, you get a possible customer, and that for each 10 possible customers, one of them actually buys a product. How many calls do I have to make in order to sell two units of product?

I think that I have to use probability theory but I'm not an expert.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you would ever get a certainty. You can, however, use cumulative probability to get above a $50\%$ chance to sell two units.

Answer (score 0):

To make two sales, you would need to call **2000** people ($\frac{2000\text{ calls}}{100\text{ calls per possible customer}}=20\text{ posssible customers}$, then $\frac{20\text{ posssible customers}}{10\text{ possible customers per customer}}=2\text{ customers}$)

---

Although, if the $100$ calls per possible customer is actually a probability of $0.01$ for each call and $10$ possible customers per customer is actually a probability of $0.1$ for each possible customer, then it would be a much different question, and you could never answer with $100\%$ certainty